# Constraint Violation on dynamic form Symfony

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

i work on Symfony3.4
I have a dynamic form country->region->city (3 distincts entities).
I can change fields based on user selection without any problem.

But i can't persist in database because of a constraint violation on the field city (and only this field)

And I realy don't know why because I call them (region and city) the same way...

Any help would be welcome.

Here is the Form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $em = $options['entityManager'];

    $builder
        ->add('rue', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'votre rue',
            'required' => true,
        ))

        ->add('pays', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Pays',
            'placeholder' => '--choisir--',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'required' => true
        ))
    ;

    $addRegion = function (FormInterface $form, Pays $pays = null) {
        $regions = null === $pays ? array() : $pays->getRegions();

        $form->add('region', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Region',
            'placeholder' => '--choisir une région--',
            'choices' => $regions,
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'required' => true
        ));

    };

    $addVille = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
        $villes = null === $region ? array() : $region->getVilles();

        $form->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Ville',
            'placeholder' => '--choisir une ville--',
            'choices' => $villes,
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'required' => true
        ));


        $form->add('submit', SubmitType::class
        );

    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($addRegion, $addVille){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $addVille($form, null);
            $addRegion($form, null);
        }
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($addRegion, $addVille, $em) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            if(isset($data['pays'])){
                $paysId = $data['pays'];

                $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Pays');
                $pays = $repo->find($paysId);

                $addRegion($form, $pays);
                $addVille($form, null);
            }
            else if(isset($data['region'])){
                $regionId = $data['region'];

                $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Region');
                $region = $repo->find($regionId);

                $addVille($form, $region);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And here is the Template :

```
{% block body %}

{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% for message in app.flashes('notice') %}
    <div style="color:green;">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

```
<script>
    var $pays = $('#adresse_pays');
    var $region = $('#adresse_region');
    var $ville = $('#adresse_ville');

    $pays.change(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
        data[$pays.attr('name')] = $pays.val();
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
                $ville.empty()
                var select = $(html).find('#adresse_ville > option')
                $ville.append(select)

                $region.empty()
                var select = $(html).find('#adresse_region > option')
                $region.append(select)
                $region.val($("#adresse_region option:first").val());
                console.log('regions')
                console.log(select)
            }
        });
    });


    $region.change(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
        data[$region.attr('name')] = $region.val();
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
                $ville.empty()
                var select = $(html).find('#adresse_ville > option')
                $ville.append(select)
                $ville.val($("#adresse_ville option:first").val());
                console.log('villes')
                console.log(select)
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

{% endblock %}

This is the alert on the form (next to city field) :
Error This value is not valid

I went further thanks to the debug bar, and it seems that this field does not send an object but an integer.

The difference i found with another field is that in the city field :

```
Normalized Format submitted is null
```

while in another field such as region :

```
Normalized Format   

Region {#6035 ▼
  -id: 3
  -nom: "Catalogne"
  -villes: PersistentCollection {#6039 …}
  -pays: Pays {#5802 ▶}
  -adresses: PersistentCollection {#6041 …}
```

}

Comment: Hi, can you paste the error message you are getting ?

Comment: Wow you're quick ! Thanks. It's done, I added the error.

Comment: Remove the `else` from ville ? You want to add it when region is set, not just if pays is not set. Seems like a logical error to me.

Comment: i works, see below. But to answer you : i guess you're talking about addVilles() ? If yes you cannot remove the else because it means you call ->getRegions() on null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works !

i split the function

$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, ... in half => i remove the else if and made another similar function to listen when "region" is changed.

What bothers me is I don't understand why it works this way but not the other way...

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($addRegion, $addVille, $em) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        if(isset($data['pays'])){
            $paysId = $data['pays'];
            $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Pays');
            $pays = $repo->find($paysId);
            $addRegion($form, $pays);
            $addVille($form, null); 
        }
    }        
);

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function(FormEvent $event) use ($addVille, $em) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        if(isset($data['region'])){
            $regionId = $data['region'];
            $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Region');
            $region = $repo->find($regionId);
            $addVille($form, $region); 
        }           
    }
);
```